# Can I put the excerpt of one page into the body of another dynamically?

Tags: php, wordpress

The theme I am using has a page called 'home' whos body is displayed on the home page.  I have another page set up called 'about' which is a detailed about page and quite long.  I want there to be text on the homepage that is a short synopsis of the about page.  I have this synopsis in the excerpt of the 'about' page.  Is there a way for me to use that excerpt in the body of the 'home' page?

By doing it this way I can tell the client that all the about information is in one page instead of telling him to go to different pages to edit things that are directly related.

edit: I want to do it without editing the themes code so through the admins page editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using "include", you could use the following to get the page excerpt of the about page and stick with native wordpress functionality:

```
$about = get_page_by_title( 'ABOUT_TITLE' );
$about_excerpt = $about->post_excerpt;
```

Then you can echo it into your theme template using:

```
<?php echo $about_excerpt; ?>
```

If you wanted to do this within the Wordpress backend, you would create a custom shortcode and wrap the above into a function to be called by that shortcode. Then you could put that shortcode wherever you wanted on any post/page.

EDIT:

Here is an example of doing this via shortcode so that you can use this for the About page or any other page with an excerpt within Wordpress:

```
add_shortcode( "Excerpt", 'nb_excerpt_shortcode' );
function nb_excerpt_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'for' => ''
), $atts) );
$page = get_page_by_title( $for );
$excerpt = $page->post_excerpt;

return $excerpt;
}
```

Then call it into action with **[Excerpt for="About" /]**

Comment: Thanks the site is down for hosting maintenance right now I will give both answers a try when it goes back up.

Comment: does that custom shortcode code go into the functions.php file?

Comment: Yes, put it in your functions.php. The shortcode of course goes into the page editor. And this assumes you have enabled excerpt support for pages (which I assume you do since you said you already had a synopsis in there).

Comment: The reason I suggest this way is that enabling php in posts/pages is a security risk and without the shortcode, the only other option would be to create a new template. So this keeps things safe and simple.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like something as simple as a PHP include of your 'about' file in your home file would give you what you are looking for ...

Place this code ( or an excerpt thereof ) in your home file, and make sure that your 'about.php' file is in the same folder...

```
<body>
    <div id="about">
        <?php include("about.php"); ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

This would allow you to make changes to your about file without directly affecting your home, but the changes would be applied to both pages...

Comment: Oh yeah sorry of course that would work I meant is there a way to do it through the admin panel sorry I should have specified.  Like can I use the php code in the body field of the home page editor

Comment: No problem - I just gave it my best answer with the information I had - I also didn't note ( maybe should have ) in reading your original post that you were in WordPress. It's tagged, but I missed it, you might mention it next time.

Comment: You are dead right I never mentioned it in the main post, thanks for helping all the same.